# Can I insert into a table using a variable instead? Using vb.net and ms access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Dim currentTable as String
currentTable = studentTable

"insert into currentTable

Versus

"insert into studentTable

I want to take what the user selects in a combobox, put it in a variable, and use that in my insert statement. Instead of just hard coding the table name.

Comment: Can you post your SQL statement? It should be something like `sqlStatement As String = "INSERT INTO " & currentTable`

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville Currently im using command = "insert into Kevin ([ClockInTime]) values ('" & Label3.Text & "')"     Instead of Kevin I want to be able to use a String instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work if you update `currentTable` with the name of the table you want to write to:

```
command = "INSERT INTO [" &  currentTable & "] ([ClockInTime]) values ('" & Label3.Text & "')"
```

Comment: How would I do this with update instead of insert?

Comment: @KyloBen - you use the exact same technique.